# Timing issue with jQuery and $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code block code when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    createDivs(); // creates some divs with class 'foo';

    // iterate
    $(".foo").each(function(index) {
        alert(index + " - " + $(this).text());
    });
}
```

I find that the "iterate" part misses the divs I created in the createDivs() method entirely! Is there some timing issue I'm not aware of? Why doesn't jquery see the divs that were just created?

Comment: Are you sure createDivs successfully creates the divs and adds them to the DOM?

Comment: You'll need to post the code in `createDivs()`.

Comment: @justkt - I open the page with Firebug and I see the divs are created correctly.

Comment: @Nick - I was silly enough to forget createDivs() created the divs in an AJAX callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Javascript is like a bull in an F1 racer when it comes to executing code. There's no making it wait to execute code in any particular chain.

You should probably create a situation where createDivs() is able to fire any dependent code after it is complete vis-a-vis a callback. Without seeing the createDivs code, it's tough to give you a way to implement it.

**UPDATE**

Really only applies if you're doing an asynchronous call (according to my friends below).

Comment: As far as I understand, if you're not doing any asynchronous work, Javascript should be executing the code sequentially.  Of course, if createDivs goes off and calls something on the server and actually creates the divs in the success callback or something along those lines, then it's all up in the air.

Comment: If you've ever tried to do this: `$('.somediv').slideUp();$('.somediv').remove();`, you know first hand code sequence in JS. I'm not sure if that falls into your definition of asynchrony, but it surprised me when I first saw it.

Comment: That is asynchronous, animations are performed on intervals.

Comment: Silly me, createDivs() was indeed creating them asynchronously in an AJAX callback.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience DOM manipulation can act asynchronous at times, possibly due to optimization by the browser, my usual solution is to have `createDivs()` return the divs created then use the returned elements aswell

```
var divs = createDivs();
$('.foo').and(divs).each(function(){
    //happy fun time
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The timing is not the issue. Maybe `createDivs()` doesn't add the elements to the DOM?

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as a comment to the question.